# Read .txt files separated by common delimiter into data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have many text files (~100) in directory that contain hotel reviews. How can I iterate over all the files and place into a data frame?
Each file name looks like `country_city_name`
The text files are all structured as follows

```
Date \t Review Title \t Review Text\n 
Date \t Review Title \t Review Text\n 
...
..
.
```

So far I have read in all files to its own df as follows:

```
beijing = 'my//path//here'

results = defaultdict(list)
for file in Path(beijing).iterdir():
    with open(file, "r") as file_open:
        results["file_name"].append(file.name)
        results["text"].append(file_open.read())
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Which looks like this:

```
file_name   text
0   china_beijing_aloft_beijing_haidian Oct 12 2009 \tNice trendy hotel location not t...
1   china_beijing_ascott_beijing    Nov 17 2009 \tgreat room layout service value-...
2   china_beijing_autumn_garden_courtyard_hotel \tVERY NICE HOTEL\tWe get vacation every year ...
```

I then created a hotel data frame and added an ID for each hotel

```
Country City    Hotel   ID
0   china   beijing aloft beijing haidian   1
1   china   beijing ascott beijing  2
2   china   beijing autumn garden courtyard hotel   3
```

I need the df to be structured as follows:

```
Review ID| Hotel ID| Date| Review Title| Review Text
1          1         xxxx  aaaa          bbbb
2          1         xxxx  aaaa          bbbb
3          2         xxxx  aaaa          bbbb
4          3         xxxx  aaaa          bbbb
```

Comment: [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt',delimiter="\t")

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('myfile.txt')

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', sep=",", header=None, names=["Pos", "Lang", "Perc"])
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.